# how do i get the current schema on DB2 if i have a JDBC conneciton?

Tags: jdbc, db2

If I have an instance of a JDBC DB2 connection, how do I get the current schema?

Either a SQL statement would work, or just a JDBC method call.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
select current_schema  
from   sysibm.sysdummy1
;
```

Comment: I tried that on iSeries DB2 v6r1, but got:
[SQL5016] Qualified object name SYSDUMMY1 not valid.