# I cant select in DB2

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I have an application consisting of: Spring, WebSphere, accessing DB2 jdbc.
Everything is set up ok, the application is usually published, because when I go to select a seat at any table I get this following error.

```
OsjsSQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator DEBUG - Translating SQLException with SQL 
state '42Y07 ', error code '30000', message [Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist]; SQL was 
[SELECT * FROM DBPROD.EXPUR_CONS_CRIVO] for task [PreparedStatementCallback]
[10/24/11 10:11:54:257 EST] 0000001b SystemOut The 10:11:54.249 [WebContainer: 1] 
ERROR bcbwahdHistoricoDescontoDAOImpl - [requestID A8IUK52K =] 
HistoricoDescontoDAOImpl.consultarHistoricoDesconto Terminating with error ()
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; 
SQL [SELECT * FROM DBPROD.EXPUR_CONS_CRIVO]; Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist; 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException nested exception is: Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist
at [spring-jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar: 3.0.1.RELEASE]
at [spring-jdbc-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar: 3.0.1.RELEASE]
```

---

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedSQLException: Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory40.wrapArgsForTransportAcrossDRDA(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    ... 191 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.catalog.DataDictionaryImpl.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.QueryTreeNode.getSchemaDescriptor(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindTableDescriptor(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromBaseTable.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.FromList.bindTables(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.SelectNode.bindNonVTITables(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bindTables(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLStatementNode.bind(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.CursorNode.bindStatement(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source) [derby-10.5.3.0_1.jar:na]
    ... 185 common frames omitted
```

my user has full access to the database, since I do not know what to do.

Comment: Can you please phrase your question in English?

Comment: `Schema 'DBPROD' does not exist` -- should there be a schema called `DBPROD`?

Comment: yes there is this schema on the bench, outside the application I can successfully do the select, when I call my method that selects the table it happens

Comment: One thing is clear - whatever database the client connected to - it does not have this schema.

Comment: but I connect the quantum of the eclipse plugin with the same username and password and I can select a bank with this eschema ... I'm confused .. lol

Comment: @Angraell Please learn how to use code blocks/spans (the `{}` icon in the editor) -- it makes things so much easier to read. I applied them for you.

Comment: Does http://db.apache.org/derby/faq.html#schema_exist help?

Comment: You say you connect to a DB2, but the exception is from a Derby driver library (org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedSQLException). So somewhere in your database configuration you obviously have configured the wrong database.

Answer (score 0):

SQL State codes beginning with '42' refer usually to Syntax errors, but in your Case its pretty clear that Schema is missing.
Check these Links hope they will help you solve this problem:

1. [CURRENT SCHEMA special register](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0005881.htm)
2. [how do i get the current schema on DB2 if i have a JDBC conneciton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121878/how-do-i-get-the-current-schema-on-db2-if-i-have-a-jdbc-conneciton)

Answer (score 0):

As it has been mentioned, the error messages you get are from an Apache Derby JDBC driver. Check that you chose the correct datasource when you configured your application in WebSphere.